# Can someone explain this valgrind output with open mpi?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, openmpi

I have an application that uses OpenMPI and launch it on Windows and Linux. The version for Windows is working fine, however, running on a Linux cause memory allocation error. The problem occurs for certain app arguments, that require more calculations. 
 To eliminate memory leaks I checked Linux version app by using Valgrind and got some [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B871wCRylUoWMWxaZHdnNFhtdEU/view?usp=sharing). After all, I tried to search information about the output and found some posts on stack overflow and GitHub(not enough reputation to attach links). After all, I updated openMPI to 2.0.2 and check app again. New [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B871wCRylUoWTTJueTB2SGdFd2M/view?usp=sharing). Is it memory leaks in OpenMPI or I'm doing something wrong?

A piece of output:

```
==16210== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 327
==16210==    at 0x4C2DBB6: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==16210==    by 0x5657A59: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==16210==    by 0x51128E6: opal_basename (in /home/vshmelev/OMPI_2.0.2/lib/libopen-pal.so.20.2.0)
==16210==    by 0x7DDECA9: ???
==16210==    by 0x7DDEDD4: ???
==16210==    by 0x6FBFF84: ???
==16210==    by 0x4E4EA9E: orte_init (in /home/vshmelev/OMPI_2.0.2/lib/libopen-rte.so.20.1.0)
==16210==    by 0x4041FD: orterun (orterun.c:818)
==16210==    by 0x4034E5: main (main.c:13)
```

OpenMPI version:Open MPI: 2.0.2
Valgrind version: valgrind-3.12.0
Virtual mashine characteristics: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

In case of using MPICH, the Valgrind output is:

```
==87863== HEAP SUMMARY:
==87863==     in use at exit: 131,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==87863==   total heap usage: 2,577 allocs, 2,575 frees, 279,908 bytes allocated
==87863== 
==87863== 131,120 bytes in 2 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==87863==    at 0x4C2DBB6: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==87863==    by 0x425803: alloc_fwd_hash (sock.c:332)
==87863==    by 0x425803: HYDU_sock_forward_stdio (sock.c:376)
==87863==    by 0x432A99: HYDT_bscu_stdio_cb (bscu_cb.c:19)
==87863==    by 0x42D9BF: HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (demux_poll.c:75)
==87863==    by 0x42889F: HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (bscu_wait.c:60)
==87863==    by 0x42863C: HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (bsci_wait.c:21)
==87863==    by 0x40B123: HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pmiserv_pmci.c:217)
==87863==    by 0x4035C5: main (mpiexec.c:343)
==87863== 
==87863== LEAK SUMMARY:
==87863==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87863==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87863==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87863==    still reachable: 131,120 bytes in 2 blocks
==87863==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87863== 
==87863== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==87863== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Links to related issues: [link 1](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/2166) and [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218056/can-someone-explain-this-valgrind-error-with-open-mpi)

Comment: Valgrind [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B871wCRylUoWQlMtTVI5WV9OWTg/view?usp=sharing) by using MPICH Version: 3.2.

Comment: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B871wCRylUoWT2RvV0ZuZ3ZzVFk/view?usp=sharing) to sources

Comment: See here https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#valgrind_clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These outputs point to some memory leak in the MPI library, not your application  code. You can safely ignore them.

More specifically, these leaks are coming from the launchers. [`ORTE`](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=developers) is the runtime environment for OpenMPI responsible for launching and managing MPI processes. [`Hydra`](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager) is the launcher and process manager for MPICH.

Answer (score 0):

The term "definitely lost" means the main function of your program at line 13 (As far as i see in the output) is leaking memory directly or calls some other function (orterun) which causes memory leak . you must fix those leaks or provide some more of your code.

take a look [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html) before everything.

Comment: However, a main.c file does not belong to my source files